# matlab: find the index of rows from the first matching column value

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a matrix,

```
>> m = magic(3)

m =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

and suppose I have a vector containing a subset of the first elements of the columns,

```
>> v = [3 4]

v =

     3     4
```

is there any function that I can use to find the index of the row from the first element of the columns? what I mean --

```
>> rows = row_index_from_col(m, 1, v)

rows =

      2     3
```

??

if not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Nice use of `ismember`! :) My only suggestion is that you make `i` a matrix, as in `I=[i',i',i']`. That way you can use `I(ismember(m,v))`, which you can use for any element in `m` all at once.

Comment: `find(any(bsxfun(@eq,m(:,1),v),2))` or `find(ismember(m(:,1),v))`?

Comment: @Divakar this is cool !!!

Comment: @ramgorur I think you can edit your deleted answer and add this code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got it --

```
m = magic(3)
v = [3 4]
[~,c] = size(m)
i = 1:c
i(ismember(m(:,1),v))
```

there might be a better way, I am not sure.